# Could not resolve host: dev.azure.com on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am not able to clone repositories from Azure Devops (Or anything for that matter) from my WSL - Windows Subsystem for Linux

```
 git clone https://dev.azure.com/Group_name/Project_name/_git/repo-name
```

Output is as follows

```
Cloning into 'repo-name'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://dev.azure.com/Group_name/Project_name/_git/repo-name': Could not resolve host: dev.azure.com
```

I tried setting these, restarting WSL but nothing is working

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy 
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

Comment: You mentioned that other repos are failing, but what about other networking commands in WSL?  Can you `ping` those same hosts successfully?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Nope I am not able to ping any hosts from my WSL, it works on my powershell though.

Comment: In that case, is there any chance that your Windows temp directory (from PowerShell, `$env:TEMP`) is compressed or encrypted?  That's a common cause of network failure in WSL.  Or if your entire Windows user profile is encrypted or compressed, that would also cause it.